# Target non-wrapped element with v-popover component

Tags: vue.js, v-tooltip

The v-popover component works great when wrapping an element inside of it, eg:

```
<v-popover offset="0" placement="right">
  <span>My awesome span</span>
  <template slot="popover">My awesome popover</template>
</v-popover>
```

However I'd like to specify the target element for the v-popover component without wrapping an element. This popover is being generated in a component that gets instantiated multiple times on the page, each with its own unique ID and popover.

After reading the [popover component reference](https://github.com/Akryum/v-tooltip#popover-component-reference) and [this GitHub discussion](https://github.com/Akryum/v-tooltip/discussions/708) the "container" or "target" options sound like the solution. I have tried:

```
<v-popover offset="0" placement="right" :container="'#' + this.id">
  <template slot="popover">My awesome popover</template>
</v-popover>
```

and

```
<v-popover offset="0" placement="right" :target="this.id">
  <template slot="popover">My awesome popover</template>
</v-popover>
```

but the popover does not appear. I have confirmed in the html that the component ID is being generated correctly and populated in the popover's attributes. What is missing?

Comment: The `container` property only defines where in the DOM the popup will be injected (to avoid it being clipped by `overflow:hidden`) - it certainly does not define the target. And I don't think there is a `target` prop anyway. If you do not show Vue components inside the popup - you should better use the `v-tooltip` directive, it can be easily attached to any desired element.

Comment: I do want to show Vue components inside the popup, which is why I'm using v-popover. So does <v-popover> have to wrap the element that it is for? There is no way to target a non-wrapped element?

Comment: Unfortunately it only triggers by the wrapped inside content.

Comment: Ok that is what I wanted to determine, thank you. If you create an answer I'll go ahead and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The v-popover component does not support targeting a non-wrapped element.